# How to take out only numbers (int and float) from a string containing mix type of characters in pandas/python?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this

```
df
col1         col2
 A         abc2.4 rs
 B         20.66
 C         sd 23.44 ()
 D         200(pw)
 E         pw 2400 (pw)
```

I want to take out only number (both int and float) from the string of col2

The final data frame should look like:

```
col1       col2
 A         2.4
 B         20.66
 C         23.44
 D         200
 E         2400
```

How to do it in most efficient way using pandas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.extract(r'(\d+\.\d+|\d+)', expand=False)
print (df)
  col1   col2
0    A    2.4
1    B  20.66
2    C  23.44
3    D    200
4    E   2400
```